# container_image full docker image tarball

Tags: docker, bazel

As mentioned [here](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_docker#container_image-1), the full docker image tarball is created as an implicit output **on demand**.
But, what does it mean by on demand? how can I inform the build to produce it?
Seems a lack of documentation here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the "image.tar" target name explicitly to build it; for instance, if your `container_image` target is named `my_image` in `//foo`, this will produce the tar archive in bazel-out:

```
bazel run //foo:my_image.tar
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually a Docker image is stored within the Docker daemon’s private filesystem space, in a complex format.  In ordinary use you’d use `docker build`, `pull`, `run`, and `rmi` to interact with an image, but none of these result in a file the way building an executable would.

There is an alternate path to managing images using `docker save` to export an image to a tar file, and `docker load` to reload it.  This is awkward and has a number of disadvantages, and you almost always want to set up a registry or use a hosted registry like Docker Hub given the option.

My read of the documentation you link to is that the Bazel task you link to by default will just run `docker build`; but, if something downstream of it demands an `image.tar` file, it will run `docker save` too.  It’s not usually needed and Bazel won’t run it if it’s not.